# DTD is prohibited in this XML document

Tags: c#, xml

do you like puzzles to resolve? This is a big one!

First, I made a lot of researches for the solution, but, my situation is still very complicated.

Well, I have a XML that is validated in a complex XSD file, but, inside that XML I also have  another complex type that is for the digital signature (xmlsignature).

My XSD is:

```
  <xsd:element name="EnviarLoteRpsEnvio">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="LoteRps" type="tcLoteRps"/>
        <xsd:element ref="dsig:Signature" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

The **LoteRps** (imagine a class like TPerson) is a complex type, and below the **LoteRps** I have my problem, the element dsig:Signature

To validate the LoteRps I have my XSD file (as described), but, to validate the **dsig:Signature**.

Well, what do I am doing?
A: I am doing a webservice that receives XML as parameter. For example:

```
ProcessLoteRps(XmlDocument loteRpsXml);
```

When I receive the Xml (that contais the elements LoteRps and Signature), I need validate the XML, to verify if the LoteRps and Signature are in the right sctruture. I don't have problem when verifying the LoteRps structure, because I can add the schema, but, when I add the schema for Signature, then I get the error. The code to validate:

```
//function that returns the erros of the XML structure - if is wrong - in a list of string    
public static List<string> ValidaXMLComXSD(XmlDocument xmlTemp)
            {
                List <string> lista_erros = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                    // add the schemas...
                    xmlTemp.Schemas.Add("http://www.abrasf.org.br/ABRASF/arquivos/nfse.xsd", "Models\XSD\NFSE.xsd");
                    // HEY BRO, THE PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
                    xmlTemp.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + @"Models\XSD\xmldsig-core-schema20020212.xsd");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Erro ao validar o XML: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
```

As we can see, I am adding 2 schemas:

1. To validate the RPS (via XSD);
2. To validate the Signature (via DTD).

If I do not add the schema for Signature, I get the following error:

```
The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature' element is not declared.
```

Ok, then, theoretically I have to add the Signature schema to validate as we can see below:

```
xmlTemp.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + @"Models\XSD\xmldsig-core-schema20020212.xsd");
```

But, when I add that schema, I get another (known) error:

```
For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
```

Well, researching at google, i found a lot of links:

[Problem validation a XML file with a local DTD file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508799/problem-validation-a-xml-file-with-a-local-dtd-file-in-c-sharp)

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Csharp/33292915/xml-prohibitdtd-error.aspx

I tried a lot of stuffs, but, still getting error..

Then I tried to invent:

public static List ValidaXMLComXSD(XmlDocument xmlTemp)
    {

```
    List <string> lista_erros = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        #region Test
        XmlErrors xmlErros = new XmlErrors();

        XmlReaderSettings xsdSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xsdSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        xsdSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(xmlErros.XmlErrorsHandler);


        XmlReaderSettings dtdSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        dtdSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
        dtdSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;
        dtdSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(xmlErros.XmlErrorsHandler);


        xmlTemp.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(NFSE_XSD_PATH, xsdSettings));
        // The error occurs below
        xmlTemp.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(NFSE_XSD_SIG_PATH, dtdSettings));
```

And a new error appears:

```
An error has occurred while opening external DTD 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd': The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
```

Then, that broken my leggs...

I don't know what to do... :s

Please, I need your help.

Best regards,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't download the schema from the server every time your program runs. You should download it once and keep it on your hard drive.

I think this will also take care of the “protocol violation” error.

Comment: Yes, but.... the browser cache should take care of this for you, every app shouldn't have to implement its own DTD caching logic.

Comment: Well, there is no browser in cases like this. And I think the default schema processor doesn't use any cache either.

Comment: This is the .NET builtin XML API, right?  I thought it used WinInet, which shares the cache with IE.

Comment: How to stop the downloading of the schema from the server?