# VB.Net - Validating XML using DTD

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I've got myself a bit of a problem that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to programatically validate a generated XML file using a DTD using the following instructions from Microsoft ([Validation Using a DTD with XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2adhb2f.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Here's my code thus far:

```
Private Sub BTN_ValidateXMLdoc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_ValidateXMLdoc.Click

    Dim JobNumber As String = Me.HNF_JobName.Value
    Dim XMLPath As String = "N:\" & JobNumber & "\" & JobNumber & ".xml"


    ' Set the validation settings.
    Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD
    settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
    settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema
    AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler, AddressOf ValidationCallBack

    ' Create the XmlReader object.
    Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(XMLPath, settings)

    ' Parse the file. 
    While reader.Read()
    End While

End Sub

' Display any validation errors.
  Private Shared Sub ValidationCallBack(sender As Object, e As ValidationEventArgs)
      MsgBox(String.Format("Validation Error: {0}", e.Message), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
  End Sub
```

Now.... Here in lies my problem. For some reason, the ValidationCallBack EventHandler never gets fired. If an error occurs during the reader.Read() executing it throws an exception error.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the ValidationCallBack sub be called?

There are errors in the XML file but instead of it being handled by the event handler it's just throwing an exception....

I'm open to any ideas as to what may be going on here?

Comment: what do mean by add the XML? It starts reading the XML file and then when a tag is malformed or there is an error in the XML file it throws an exception instead of firing the eventhandler

Comment: DTDs use a formal grammar to describe the structure and syntax of compliant XML documents; "they specify content and values allowed for the XML document." - If it is not a valid XML it will fail

Comment: so.....basically your saying that if there is an error with the XML, the doc can't be validated? And if it is a valid XML doc, then validation will be run on the values of the entities etc.

Comment: No as per my understanding, the XML should be valid, validation against DTD is for verifying whether the elements are values are correct, like if there a Price tag, it should not be -ve value.

Comment: So, the doc needs to be a valid XML doc before it can validated - correct?

Comment: AFAIK, yes it should be a valid XML

Comment: Anuraj, you've got it wrong, and the original questioner expectations are reasonable. Try out the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.schemas.aspx and see what happens. The event *will* occur if invalid content is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Your code implies the DTD is embedded in the XML document itself. While that's possible, it's unlikely to be what you want. I suspect your test is failing because there is no embedded DTD in the actual XML document.

If the DTD is indeed external to the XML document, you need to tell your XmlReaderSettings where to find it.

Remove the line

`settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema` from your code.

Make sure there's a DOCTYPE in your XML document to specify the DTD. If there isn't, you may need to insert it before validation.

If you want to escape the overhead of downloading the DTD each time, you should create an XmlResolver. See [Problem validation a XML file with a local DTD file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508799/problem-validation-a-xml-file-with-a-local-dtd-file-in-c-sharp) for an example.

Consider converting your DTD to an XML Schema. Schemas are more natural in XmlReader. DTDs don't understand XML namespaces.